# Sum of Values in SortedList and Condition on Keys

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sum up certain values (time range start till end) of a `SortedList<DateTime, double>` with linq. The Keys contain dates of workingdays and the Values contain the number of possible workhours for the given day. The question I want to answer is, how many hours are possible in a given timeframe.

I managed to get a count of the keys, but I'm stuck now at the sum.

The code to count the keys (Thanks to stackoverflow) looks like this:

```
        double ats = (from n in DaysAndHours.Keys
                   where n >= start
                   where n <= end
                   select n).Count();
```

How do I have to change it, to fill `ats` with values in the date range?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is handy to tell something about what the keys of your DaysAndHours are? There is enough information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641682/linq-to-sql-sum-without-group-into

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just updated the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming post applying condition you want to add the values, then use the following code and modify as required

```
double result = DaysAndHours.Where(n => n.Key >= start)
                            .Where(n => n.Key <= end)
                            .Sum(n => n.Value)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!